# Labeling file upload button

Tags: html, internationalization, dialog

How can I internationalize the button text of the file picker?  For example, what this code presents to the user:

```
 <input type="file" .../>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pure CSS solution:

```css
.inputfile {
  /* visibility: hidden etc. wont work */
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.inputfile:focus + label {
  /* keyboard navigation */
  outline: 1px dotted #000;
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
.inputfile + label * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile">
<label for="file">Choose a file (Click me)</label>
```

source: [http://tympanus.net/codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/)

Comment: What after I select my file? I can't see it

Comment: @random_18 This is the trick, the "file" input is not really visible, the label is...

Comment: Although this one is marked as winner, it makes inivisble the fact you selected a file.

Answer (score 35):

It is normally provided by the browser and hard to change, so the only way around it will be a CSS/JavaScript hack,

See the following links for some approaches:

- http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom
- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic15621.htm

Comment: Note that the browser might trigger a clickjacking warning (currently in FF+NoScript and IE9, IIRC), as this is the same technical method.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the question here.  It's relatively simple to re-style a file input element without alerting the user to this fact.

Answer (score 19):

Take a step back!  Firstly, you're assuming the user is using a foreign locale on their device, which is not a sound assumption for justifying taking over the button text of the file picker, and making it say what ***you*** want it to.

It is reasonable that you want to control every item of language visible on your page.  The content of the File Upload control is not part of the HTML though.  There is more content behind this control, for example, in WebKit, it also says "No file chosen" next to the button.

There are very hacky workarounds that attempt this (e.g. like those mentioned in @ChristopheD's answer), but none of them truly succeed:

- To a screen reader, the file control will still say "Browse..." or "Choose File", and a custom file upload will not be announced as a file upload control, but just a button or a text input.
- Many of them fail to display the chosen file, or to show that the user has no longer chosen a file
- Many of them look nothing like the native control, so might look strange on non-standard devices.
- Keyboard support is typically poor.
- An author-created UI component can never be as fully functional as its native equivalent (and the closer you get it to behave to suppose IE10 on Windows 7, the more it will deviate from other Browser and Operating System combinations).
- Modern browsers support drag & drop into the native file upload control.
- Some techniques may trigger heuristics in security software as a potential ‘click-jacking’ attempt to trick the user into uploading file.

Deviating from the native controls is always a risky thing, there is a whole host of different devices your users could be using, and whatever workaround you choose, you will not have tested it in every one of those devices.

However, there is an even bigger reason why all attempts fail from a User Experience perspective: there is even more non-localized content behind this control, the file selection dialog itself.  Once the user is subject to traversing their file system or what not to select a file to upload, they will be subjected to the host Operating System locale.

Are you sure you're doing your user any justice by deviating from the native control, just to localize the text, when as soon as they click it, they're just going to get the Operating System locale anyway?

The best you can do for your users is to ensure you have adequate localised guidance surrounding your file input control.  (e.g. Form field label, hint text, tooltip text).

Sorry. :-(

--

This answer is for those looking for any justification *not* to localise the file upload control.

Answer (score 13):

You get your browser's language for your button. There's no way to change it programmatically.

Comment: i like your answer because it means i dont have to do anything =) but the solution below you looks like it would work

Comment: It seems so! :) Using JavaScript could do the trick, but be wary that won't work for users with JS disabled and you'll end up with different layouts. On top of that, you would see a layout first (the typical button) and, after a small delay, the change through JS.

Comment: "solution below you", when I'm looking at it; Seb's is the last answer :)

Answer (score 12):

much easier  use it

```
<input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="Custom Button Name"onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: Very clever indeed!

Comment: Display none will prevent the element data from being submitted.

Answer (score 3):

I could achieve a button using jQueryMobile with following code:

```
<label for="ppt" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-corners="false">Upload</label>
<input id="ppt" type="file" name="ppt" multiple data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-corners="false" style="opacity: 0;"/>
```

Above code creates a "Upload" button (custom text). On click of upload button, file browse is launched. Tested with Chrome 25 & IE9.

Answer (score 0):

To make a custom "browse button" solution simply try making a hidden browse button, a custom button or element and some Jquery. This way I'm not modifying the actual "browse button" which is dependent on each browser/version. Here's an [example.](http://jsfiddle.net/nimjox/r5vmaqhx/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="import" type="file">My Custom Button</div>
<input id="browser" class="hideMe" type="file"></input>
```

CSS:

```
#import {
  margin: 0em 0em 0em .2em;
  content: 'Import Settings';
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #ddd #bbb #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font: bold 12px/1.2 Arial,sans-serif !important;
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#C2C1C1), to(#2F2727));
}

.hideMe{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#import").click(function() {
    $("#browser").trigger("click");
    $('#browser').change(function() {
            alert($("#browser").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible to customize the `Upload File` button with its pseudo selector: `::file-selector-button`.

Check this for more info: [MDN ::file-selector-button - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button)