# Give a different value to form input

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a Spring project and I need some help. In my JSPs pages I am using spring form tags. For example:

```
<form:input size="30" type="file" path="attachment" />
```

I need to know how can I give this tag an option to overwrite the word "browse", so that I can use  tag to call different text from .properties file.
I've tried to use title, and value options and it never worked.

The reason I need to do it is to show "voir" in case of French language, "浏览" in case of Chinese, and so on.

Comment: I can't understand the question at all.

Comment: Bozho, Ali wants to create button that opens browse dialog but has custom label. For example imagine button with lable "Press to attach your file" that opens browse dialog. IMHO it is impossible. This is under browser's control.

Comment: @AlexR: Not really. Have look at the thread link, I posted as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Labeling file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normally provided by the browser and hard to change, so the only way around it will be a CSS/JavaScript hack, see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button).

Comment: with your rep pointing to another thread should be done in the proper way (close as duplicate) or, at least, with a more elaborate answer.

Comment: @Frankie: How about this ;)? However, my answer was not qualifying for a negative, though. But its okay, as you like it.

Comment: that comes close to what I was expecting from a pro user like yourself! ;) Vote updated.