# jQuery MultiFile choose file button

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I use jQuery MultiFile plugin. The upload button below:

[image: Choose File button]

Can I change **Choose File** text to something else?? Web-surfing can't help me.

I just want a "Choose Files" there.

Please, just say *Yes(+and how) or *No.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Labeling file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I found best workaround! This is not a hack - we just need 2 buttons: original, and 'fake'.

```
  <input type="button" value="Choose Files">
  <input type="file">
```

Fake is displayed to user, and has

```
  z-index:1
```

Original is positioned above it, with

```
  z-index:2, opacity: 0; position: relative;
```

and has callbacks:

```
  :onmousedown=>"buttonPush('depressed')", :onmouseup=>"buttonPush('normal')"

  function buttonPush(buttonStatus) {
    if (buttonStatus == "depressed")
      document.getElementById("fake_btn").style.borderStyle = "inset";
    else
      document.getElementById("fake_btn").style.borderStyle = "outset";
  }
```

Thanks to this link
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/15621-styling-a-file-browse-button/

Regards @Piskvor, @racar

Comment: You rock!  Add style="visibility:hidden" to the file button and you are golden.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a part of the `<input type="file">` control, and the webpage cannot control its appearance.

Comment: some workaround here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button

Comment: @racar: That is indeed a hack - a rather ugly hack, IMHO; and it will get flagged as clickjacking (because it is, however benign): http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/more-advanced-clickjacking-ui-redress-attacks/ Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, though.

Comment: I understand. Can I hide the file control, and 'activate' it via jquery/javascript ?

Comment: i agree, but it's not my choice

Comment: @racar: I'm not saying it is :) OTOH, adding a piece of code which will trigger severe warning messages (currently in IE9 and FF+NoScript) doesn't sound very user-friendly to me.

Comment: I wondered that we can not use simple solution for this trivial task. I really don't want use any hacking there, and should use flash-plugin to change this ugly text to something else.