# Custom browse button to upload a fle

Tags: javascript

Hi I have currently custom 2 button called Browse and Import. I also have a input type as a text. My question is how i can browse and select a record and place in input type text

Please advise

```
<input type="button" id="btnBrowse" value="Browse" onclick="document.getElementById('fileID').click(); return false" style="height:31px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" />
       <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Import" style="height:31px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" />
       <input type="text" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Don't programmatically click a file input element.  It looks like you are trying to do that here.  You will run into security exceptions in IE when you try to actually send the file to the server via js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can however customize nearly any other html element.
Here is a complete solution:

```
<input id="btn" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="document.getElementById('file').value=this.value.substring(this.value.lastIndexOf('\\')+1);">

<input id="file" type="text" style="width:200px;">

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('btn').click();" value="click me" />
```

Comment: This is generally bad advice.  You should never programmatically trigger an input file element.  If you do so, and then submit the file to the server via javascript, IE will throw a security exception.  Various versions of other browsers may prevent this as well.  The only safe way to style a file input is via CSS, as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: oh, for pete's sake, who said we were submitting via javascript? a submit button will work just fine here. Sometimes the simplest answer really is the best one.

Comment: Hi iGanja, Actually, it said the selected file is null

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can style a file input button.  This has been covered over, and over, and over again on SO.  For example, [Labeling file upload button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button/686919).

Comment: Actually answer is (citation of Ray's link): It is normally provided by the browser and hard to change, so the only way around it will be a CSS/JavaScript hack.

Comment: @Ulflander That's correct, but I wouldn't say it's hard to change.  I guess it's all relative.  EDIT: I'm assuming you were referring to the CSS/JS required to style the button.

Comment: That was a citation, but you're right, the "hard" part is about hacking it :)

Comment: WOW, I thought I was going to learn something new today, alas, no. The fact is it CANNOT be changed natively, as I said. There are, of course, countless ways to get around this. I posted one very simple method below.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Comment: no, you cannot customize the browse button of a input type="file"

Comment: @iGanja Yes, you can.  Do a quick search on SO for details.  This is a FAQ.