# The File Upload control from the Extension Library doesn't seem to localize. Where can I change that?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using the Extension Library File Upload control in a localized application.  As you can see in the screen shot, most elements are "automagically" localized, but the File Upload control is not.  It seems the download control has properties to override the names for "Created on" and such, which is perfect, I can localize those, but the "Browse" button on the upload control doesn't seem to have any property to change what is displayed.  Any way I can override that?

[image: upload control]

Comment: Since it is the browser that renders the button it will feel "natural" consistent with all other pages

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. It's a browser limitation but hacking is possible...

I found this very useful:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

There is a similar question with alternative ideas:

[Labeling file upload button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button)