# Localize XPages's FileUpload Contol's Browse button label

Tags: file-upload, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I am working on localization for a XPages enabled web application. I want to localize the default "Browse" button's label to the XPage's fileupload control. Is it possible without creating separate button kind of workaround?

In the same way, is it possible to localize the default Header title labels(like File Name, Size, etc.,) of XPage's FileDownload control?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the upload button label without workarounds like http://stackoverflow.com/a/20803066/2065611

Comment: You can change the labels of the file upload control in the attributes of the component (f.e."lastModifiedTitle")

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: Could you please expand your comment.

Comment: @Karthick: go in `xp:fileDownload` to `All Properties`. There you can set the titles for "createdTitle", "lastModifiedTitle" and other "...Title" properties.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: Thanks for your tips. I have implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Browser button is part of the Browser, not part of your code. In short: don't waste your time. If a user desperately needs a different language, they will have switched the language in their browser settings already and your work is done.

The Browse button label is subject to the same access rules as the Browser menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to change the **upload** button label without workarounds.

Usually, it's not necessary to localize upload button label as it is set by browser for current language automatically. Only if you'd like to use from browser setting's *different language* or if you want to *style* the upload button with css then you would use one of the workarounds you can find e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20803066/2065611) or Google for "css file upload button".

Much easier it is with XPages **fileDownload** control. You can set the titles for "fileNameTitle", "sizeTitle" and other "...Title" properties at `All Properties` tab:

[image]

But, usually you don't have to localize titles here neither as that happens automatically for selected language in browser settings.