# Input type=File File Upload Language

Tags: html, file-upload, multilingual

I am using file browse control to upload file to server. HTML as below:

```
<input id="fileUpload"  type="file" class="" multiple="" required="" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

It renders as follow in IE

[image]

And as below in Chrome:
[image]

I want to change its language. e.g "***Browse***" to "***feuilleter***"
and "***No File Chosen***" to "***Aucun fichier choisi***"

How we can do this.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button

Comment: I did a short search and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Try this.

Comment: this also may helpful to you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you want your browser to change its language to be in french. Mine is in french and 
`<input id="fileUpload"  type="file" class="" multiple="" required="" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />`

gives me on Chrome 
[image]

And
[image] on Firefox

Your problem is that your browsers are in english

Answer (score 0):

According to your browser language it will be updated , if you want to change it still ,you need to design your own layout using css.