# Default language of fileInput widget in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

How can I change the language of Shyni widget fileInput?

In fact, it seems to be chosen automatically. For instance, in this example I'd like to have english labels for all users:
http://joxi.ru/zAND3PEslwzZBm

Comment: It's likely a combination of whether you've specified a label and your computer's locale variables.

Comment: I'm fairly certain (but not 100%) that this is not a shiny question but rather an HTML problem. Shiny is simply creating an HTML input of type "file", and each browser is responsible for rendering it the way it wants. A quick google search for "html change file input text" showed me that a lot of people ask about this, but there isn't an easy way to do it. Here are two StackOverflow threads about this [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button) and [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file)