# React hidden input type file onChange not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const passFromPicToUpload = (e) =>{
        hiddenFileInput.current.click();
        console.log("one")
    }

const handleProfilePicUpload = (e) =>{
    console.log("two")

    if(e.target.files[0]){
        setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        
    }
}

 return (
     <div className="profile">
      <div className="imageContainer" >
       <a href="#" onClick={passFromPicToUpload}>
        {
          profile.avatarUrl?<Image src={profile.avatarUrl} className="profile__image"  /> :<Image src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png" className="profile__image" /> 
        }
       </a>
      </div>   
     <input type="file" ref={hiddenFileInput} onChange={handleProfilePicUpload} style={{display:'none'}} /> 

 </div>
)
```

So basically the file choosing window is showing but after I choose a pic the "handleProfilePicUpload" is not firing.

Comment: Please show us the whole component. Also, why is that 'display: none'?

Comment: Why don't you simply use [label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686905/2873538)?

Comment: Did the below answers help you? If so, please [accept or vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/329117)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to simulate `onChange` by `click` event. Change the listener to `onClick`:

```
<input onClick={handleProfilePicUpload} .. />
```

A cleaner solution would be using a label:

```html
<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none;">
<label for="file">
   <a>Image</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a label:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="my-file" class="hidden">
<label for="my-file">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="100" height="100"> 
</label>
```

It will work exactly as an HTML file `input` tag works.

So, you can do:

```
function onFileChange(e) {
  setImage(e.target.files)
}

// ...

<label
  htmlFor="my-file"
  title="Click to choose a file"
>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="100" height="100">
</label>
<input
  type="file"
  id="my-file"
  className="hidden"
  onChange={onFileChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
   type="file"
   accept="image/*"
   name="pic"
   onChange={(e: any) => {}}
   style={{ display: 'none' }}
   ref={fileRef}
/>
```

> If you hide the input through styles onChange does get fired but make sure your component is mounted before your call click through the reference

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality answers on Stack Overflow. This answer could be improved with an explanation as to how this solves OP's problem presented in the question.